# setEndTime must be called after setStartTime

Tags: jmeter, jms

Trying pushing message using JMeter JMS Publisher. But getting below error. Is this jmeter side error or server side error.

Error:

```
setEndTime must be called after setStartTime java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence at 
org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.setEndTime(SampleResult.java:1058)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue either with your configuration or the jms server.

And there is a bug fixed in current nightly build (future 5.0) that made the error message confusing:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62464